# Auto start video recording in android

Tags: android-emulator

I am opening the camcorder application using command "adb shell am start -n com.android.gallery3d/com.android.camera.VideoCamera"

But after that I need to start video recording, so is there any command or any thing to start video recording automatically.

Thanks
Jitendra

Answer (score 0):

The following statements should start video recording mode. Then use Camera Key events to start and stop.

```
package = "com.android.gallery3d"
activity = "com.android.camera.VideoCamera"
action = "android.media.action.VIDEO_CAMERA"runComponent = package + '/' + activity
device.startActivity(component=runComponent,action=action)
```